# Bootstrap progress bar background not changing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having trouble with implementing a bootstrap progress bar.

in my view I have the line

```
<%= raw progress_bar(company.contact_step)%>
```

I made a helper like this

```
def progress_bar(step)
  if step.interested
    bg = "bg-danger"
    value = "100"
  elsif  step.sell_sheet_submitted
    bg = "bg-success"
    value = "75"
  elsif step.contact_made
    bg = "bg-success"
    value = "50"
  elsif step.contact_attempted_phone
    bg = ""
    value = "25"
  elsif step.contact_attempted_email
    bg = ""
    value = "10"
  else
    bg = ""
    value = "1"
  end

  pb = %Q[<div class=\'progress\'>
            <div class=\'#{bg} progress-bar \' 
              role=\'progressbar\' 
              style=\'width: #{value}%\' 
              aria-valuenow=\'#{value}\' 
              aria-valuemin=\'0\' 
              aria-valuemax=\'100\'>
            </div>
          </div>]
  end
```

So based on the attributes it should modify the progress bar value and the  background class that is applied. If I inspect the page everything looks like it should

However, the bg-success class is being overridden by the progress-bar class so the bar is blue when I want it to be green. I can hit the checkbox next to the background-color in the inspector to suppress it and it will turn a light green. What am I missing?

**EDIT:**
as was alluded to in the comments and one answer I was importing bootstrap twice so I got rid of that but the issue still exists so here is the new image of inspecting the progress bar. One of the things I noticed is that the color for bg-success class is wrong in my inspection the color is #dffod8 while if I inspect the bootstrap page for [progress bars](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/progress/)  it is supposed to be 
background-color: #5cb85c!important

[image: new inspecting the progress bar]

I think the problem is that I am using the bootstrap-sass gem which is bootstrap version 2-3 while the bootstrap progress bar code I was working from is version 4. Were the classes I am using changed from v3 to v4?

Comment: not sure, but looks like you may be including bootstrap twice? Might be causing your issue.

Answer (score 1):

so the problem is that I was using the bootstrap-sass gem which is bootstrap version 2-3 while the bootstrap [progress bar v4](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/progress/?) code I was working from is version 4.

so the code I should be using for the [progress bar v3](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#progress) and indeed the classes have changed in version 3 it would be

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 40%"></div>
</div>
```

while in version 4 it is now

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar bg-success" role="progressbar" style="width: 25%" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
```

I guess the lesson is bootstrap version 3 an 4 code is not interchangeable and I should be more careful what documentation I am using.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `css` code in `application.css` line `15650` and `10930`.

To learn more about css specificity

https://duckduckgo.com/?q=css+specificity&atb=v52-6_b&ia=web

Your class `.progress-bar` is defined twice, at line `6800` and `15650`, while your class `.bg-success` is defined at line `10930`.

As the two `css classes` have the same specificity, they are just a single selector(class) on an html, the one prevailing will be the last one in the stylesheet.

This is the reason `CSS` stands for **cascade style sheets**

Probably you are importing in `applications.css` some bootstrap and maybe also bootstrap has a class called `.progress-bar` and in that case it may be the reason you have it twice at row `15650` and `10930`